How to Post Using the linkedin API
I want to create a post using the API. I am following the OAuth 2.0 guide but I am stuck at obtaining the token. I am facing restrictions related to the scope information. When creating an OAuth 2.0 access token, I can select scopes like openid, profile, w_member_social, and email. However, to use the authentication API, I need to use r_liteprofile, but I am having trouble finding where to set this. Please provide a guide on how to use the post creation API.
I have found that the authentication method for API usage has changed between 2022 and 2023. However, there is no official information or guidance on this, so I have been consulting various sources like Stack Overflow. Some posts suggest that it is now necessary to partner with LinkedIn to use their API. Since Stack Overflow is not an official channel for inquiries about specific companies, I am reaching out to LinkedIn to confirm whether there has been an official change in the API authentication process. Can you please provide clarification on this matter?

Idk if it will be any help, but here it is fresh documentation for the topic https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2024-05&tabs=http#permissions
There you will see you need permissions:
w_organization_social
r_organization_social
w_member_social
r_member_social

Last time I've checked, you get those permissions by adding Share on LinkedIn and Sign in etc. products in your app. Do not forget to generate another token after all changes you've made. Also, you can check token permissions on the oauth2.0tools page.
Then there is POST example on documentation page you can use, just alter ids, but be careful, if it will be successful, people will see it :) Recommend to use test profile or not well known profile for testing
